# Creating blurred box for login

Tags: html, css, image

I'm designing a login page for a friend, and I'm trying to make a blurred box over an image. This is what i have to far,

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepage.css">

<!-- Page starts here -->

<body id="bg">
  <div class="center">
    <div id="image" class="image center">
      <img>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css

```
#bg {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.funchap.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/amazing-horse-pictures.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -2;
  margin: 0;
}
.image {
 background-size: cover;
 height: 62%;
 width: 22.5%;
 -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
 -moz-filter: blur(10px);
 -o-filter: blur(10px);
 -ms-filter: blur(10px);
 filter: blur(10px);
 overflow: hidden;
 border-style: hidden;
 border-radius: 25px;
 border-color: transparent;
}
.image img {
  background: url(http://www.funchap.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/amazing-horse-pictures.jpg) center;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300%;
  width: 300%;

}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#logo {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 13%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
}
```

I'm not sure why it's not lining up in the box. Any help is welcome.

P.S. the horse image is 2560 x 1600 if you're wondering.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this do: **<img>**

Comment: Suggest looking at your code for `.image img` - you cannot set background properties on an empty `img` tag and expect it to work. Either put the image url in a `src` attribute on the img tag, or use a block element with background.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SVG effect.

```
`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  version="1.1">
<defs>
<filter id="blur">
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>`
```

[Working Example](http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/d056d1b26b9683c018f9bb9e0f1b0e1c)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Login</h2>
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username"><br><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</div>

css

body{
background-image: url(Beautiful-White-Horse.jpg);
background-size:cover;
}
.container{
width:300px;
height:260px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:40px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:50px;
border-radius:15px;
-webkit-border-radius:15px;
-o-border-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius:15px;
color:#FFF;
font-weight:bold;
box-shadow:inset -4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
font-size:18px;
}
.container input[type="text"]{
width:200px;
height:35px;
border:0;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-o-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
padding-left:5px;
}
.container input[type="password"]{
width:200px;
height:35px;
border:0;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-o-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
padding-left:5px;
}
.container input[type="submit"]{
width:100px;
height:35px;
border:0;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-o-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background-color:#0FF;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Please try it. May be you want something like that.